# what do compilers do for the returns_twice attribute?

Tags: gcc, glibc

What are compilers required to do with the [returns_twice](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) attribute, which is supported by GCC and required for glibc functions like `setjmp` and `fork`?

I've seen statements that `returns_twice` functions cannot be inlined and need to issue warnings about register clobbering, but I cannot find a clear description of how a compiler needs to implement this.

Comment: Are you asking because you are writing a compiler? Because you have a function that you are considering decorating with this attribute? Other? I don't think fork is returns_twice (vfork could be). Essentially, returns_twice means whatever magic is needed for setjmp to work properly...

Comment: I am asking from the perspective of implementing it in a compiler, meaning the technical details of "whatever magic is needed for setjmp to work properly".  I understand how and why to use the attribute in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `returns_twice` depends on the optimizations the compiler implements.  For example, if the compiler has optimizations which can eliminate the read of the `local` variable in the following fragment (assuming that its address is never taken, so that `setjmp` would not ordinarily be able to update it), it needs to know that `setjmp` can return spontaneously, so that it does not apply the optimizations in this case:

```
static int local;

static doit (void)
{
  jmp_buf jmp;
  local = 0;
  if (setjmp (jmp) != 0)
    return local;
  local = 1;
  longjmp (jmp, 1);
  local = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

(Curiously, GCC does *not* do this if you turn `local` into a global register variable.  Perhaps a bug.)